# What are the returned values of python os.fork()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe

Python `os.pipe()` and `os.fork()` are new to me and I have a few basic questions about them. There is a code taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-fork-method/#:%7E:text=fork()%20method%20in%20Python,id%20in%20the%20parent%20process.) as follows:

```
# Python program to explain os.fork() method

# importing os module
import os


# Create a child process
# using os.fork() method
pid = os.fork()

# pid greater than 0 represents
# the parent process
if pid > 0 :
    print("I am parent process:")
    print("Process ID:", os.getpid())
    print("Child's process ID:", pid)

# pid equal to 0 represents
# the created child process
else :
    print("\nI am child process:")
    print("Process ID:", os.getpid())
    print("Parent's process ID:", os.getppid())


# If any error occurred while
# using os.fork() method
# OSError will be raised
```

and the output is:

```
I am Parent process
Process ID: 10793
Child's process ID: 10794

I am child process
Process ID: 10794
Parent's process ID: 10793
```

When I print out `pid`, two integers are displayed, one of which is always 0. According to the code comments, *pid greater than 0 represents the parent process*, if this is the case then why inside `if pid > 0` block, which means pid value corresponds to the parent, there is `print("Child's process ID:", pid)` where the value of pid is associated with the child's process ID? Also, as `pid` returns two values how are they handled in both `if` and `else` statements as according to the output both `if` and `else` are executed?

Comment: A PID greater than 0 means you _are_ the parent process, so you're receiving the process identifier of the child you're responsible for `wait()`ing for (if it exits, you get a SIGCHLD informing you of that exit; if you ignore that signal and don't `wait()` for the child, it becomes a zombie until you die and your parent inherits the responsibility). The word "represents" is very poorly chosen.

Comment: Beyond that, do you have a narrow, specific question? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Return 0 in the child and the child’s process id in the parent.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My other question as I mentioned is why both `if` and `else` are executed?

Comment: @plpm, obviously, one happens in the parent and the other happens in the child. _In each process_ only one of the two takes place, but `fork()` creates a new child process.

Comment: @plpm: Key thing to remember about `fork()` is that it returns _twice_ -- once in the parent, and once in the newly-created child process.

Comment: The linked article states that "This method returns 0 in the child process and child’s process id in the parent process." What else are you looking for? "as pid returns two values" What makes you think that? `os.fork` returns one value per process.

Comment: @FredLarson now I see what is happening, thank you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy *The word "represents" is very poorly chosen.* True, "represents" was misleading. Thank you for your all explanations.

Comment: I must add that in twenty years of Python programming, I've never had to use fork() and pipe().  Python's has a multiprocessing module that presents a much cleaner interface and is much simpler to use.

Comment: Remember that most of the functions in the `os` module call operating system services directly.  You could have Googled for `fork` and received many excellent explanations.

Comment: @FrankYellin Can *multiprocessing module* be used for sending data such as messages between two or more processes? And is there any restriction on the number of processes spawned due to the machine configuration?

Comment: @FrankYellin I found the documentation, send and receive are available. but I'm not sure how many processes can be spawned?

Comment: @plpm, yes, there are limits, but they're not Python-specific; you want to look for general OS-specific docs. And you'll hit those same limits with `fork()`; they're not specific to multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: os.fork() return 0 in the child and the child’s process id in the parent. If an error occurs OSError is raised.